# 11.10 to 12.04 upgrade Video issues

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, ati

I was using Ubuntu 11.10 without any difficulties now after the upgrade, during boot up i get A message indicating Ubuntu can not figure out my monitor or video card settings should be and goes to low res.  I get a login prompt but since I am new I am used to the GUI.  I am not sure how to get to the GUI or how to fix this issue.

Please Help Me ASAP.
Thanks in Advance!

**System Info:**

- ASUS M4A89GTD PRO/USB3 AM3 AMD 890GX SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 HDMI ATX AMD Motherboard,
- AMD Phenom II X4 955 Black Edition Deneb 3.2GHz Socket AM3 125W Quad-Core Processor HDZ955FBGIBOX,
- using Philips 55" HDMI input 2 as my monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing your xorg.conf file:

press ctrl + alt + 1 to log in to a terminal.
After you've logged in, write

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.orig
```

now reboot

```
sudo reboot 0
```

if this doesn't work, you can switch back your xorg.conf by

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf.orig /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and reboot again.